# Problemas con Visual Studio 2022 y C++ 20

Tags: c++20, visual-studio-2022

Me estoy iniciando en el entorno de Visual Studio, y mi experiencia es muy escasa.
Después de algunos escarceos con C++, me ha dado por probar con C++ 20.

Para configurarlo, he seguido las instrucciones de video:
[Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 for C++ 20](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XsDR01GMxEI)

He copiado el código que figura en el video para comprobar que acepta las nuevas facilidades de C++ 20, pero me aparecen errores, que no se corregir.

Adjunto código fuente empleado.

```
#include <iostream>

consteval int get_value() {
    return 3;
}

int main() {
    constexpr int value = get_value();
    std::cout << "value : " << value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Capturas de los errores que me aparecen, así como visualización de la propiedad de que el compilador seleccionado es C++ 20:

[image: Captura resultado compilacion]

Captura de la pantalla con el código fuente:
[image: Captura código fuente]

Para ver si podía obtener mas información o alguna pista sobre el problema, probé con una nueva fuente que tomé de:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval

El código, que reproduzco a continuación, es el ejemplo que aparace al final de esa página:

```
#include <iostream>

// This function might be evaluated at compile-time, if the input
// is known at compile-time. Otherwise, it is executed at run-time.
constexpr unsigned factorial(unsigned n)
{
    return n < 2 ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1);
}

// With consteval we enforce that the function will be evaluated at compile-time.
consteval unsigned combination(unsigned m, unsigned n)
{
    return factorial(n) / factorial(m) / factorial(n - m);
}

static_assert(factorial(6) == 720);
static_assert(combination(4, 8) == 70);

int main(int argc, const char* [])
{
    constexpr unsigned x{ factorial(4) };
    std::cout << x << '\n';

    [[maybe_unused]]
    unsigned y = factorial(argc); // OK
    //  unsigned z = combination(argc, 7); // error: 'argc' is not a constant expression
}
```

Incluyo, también, las capturas de los errores de la compilación, y la captura de la
pantalla con el código fuente.

Captura errores:
[image: Texto]
Captura pantalla codigo fuente:
[image: Texto]

**Me llama la atención, en este caso, el mensaje señalado en rojo**, que parece indicar que, para algo que figura en el código, se requerrirìa al menos C++ 17.

No se, pero me hace dudar de si realmente se está empleando C++ 20.

**No tengo interés en la facilidad consteval**, sino en saber que estoy empleado C++ 20.

Me podeis ayudar a interpretar que pasa o que estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como se puede ver en las capturas, el estándar está establecido en **C++20** para todas las  configuraciones de la plataforma **Win32** (en más **Property Pages**).

Mientras que estás intentando compilar el proyecto para la plataforma **x64**. Puedes verlo al lado del triángulo verde.

En las **Property Pages** cambia la plataforma a **x64** y asegúrate de que también tenga la configuración deseada.

Comment: ¡¡Perfecto!!. He cambiado, en Properties Pages, a **todas las configuraciones y todas las plataformas**, y han desaparecido los errores. Tengo que prestar mas atención a los detalles.

Comment: Cuidado con cambiar todas las configuraciones al mismo tiempo. Con algunos ajustes no hay problema, pero por ejemplo, si asocias una librería de 64 bits a la configuración de 32 no funcionará.

Comment: ¡Buena reflexión!.